# Unable to navigate from one page to another in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have create an appointment page which consists of to button ie addappointment and homepage.But when I am trying to click on this appointment option ,the app stops..Unable to find any error...Please help

Tab1.java

```
package com.example.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Tab1 extends Activity 
{

    private ListView infoListView ;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

       // Find the ListView resource.   
            infoListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.infoListView );  

            // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
            String[] person = new String[] { "Persons","Encounter", "Medications","Weight","BloodPressure",
                                              "BloodSugar","Lab and Test Results","Office Visit","Office Info","Data Analysis","Appointment","Allergy","Problem"};    
            ArrayList<String> personList = new ArrayList<String>();  
            personList.addAll( Arrays.asList(person) );  

            // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.inforow, personList);  


            // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
            infoListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  
           /* infoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    Intent i3=new Intent(Info.this,Call.class);
                    startActivity(i3);

                }

            });*/

            infoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) 
                {
                     switch (position) 
                     {
                        case 0:
                            Intent i1= new Intent (Tab1.this ,Person.class);
                            startActivity(i1);
                            break;
                        case 1 :
                        Intent i2 = new Intent (Tab1.this ,History.class);
                        startActivity(i2);
                        break;

                        case 2 :
                            Intent i3 = new Intent (Tab1.this , Medications.class);
                            startActivity(i3);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Intent i4 = new Intent (Tab1.this , Weight.class);
                            startActivity(i4);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Intent i5 = new Intent (Tab1.this , BloodPressure.class);
                            startActivity(i5);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Intent i6 = new Intent (Tab1.this , BloodSugar.class);
                            startActivity(i6);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Intent i7 = new Intent (Tab1.this , LabAndTestResults.class);
                            startActivity(i7);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            Intent i8 = new Intent (Tab1.this , OfficeVisit.class);
                            startActivity(i8);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            Intent i9 = new Intent (Tab1.this , Office_info_button.class);
                            startActivity(i9);
                            break;

                        case 9:
                            Intent i10 = new Intent (Tab1.this ,SimpleListActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i10);
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            Intent i11 = new Intent (Tab1.this ,Appointment1.class);
                            startActivity(i11);
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            Intent i12 = new Intent (Tab1.this ,Allergy.class);
                            startActivity(i12);
                            break;

                        case 12:
                            Intent i13 = new Intent (Tab1.this ,ProblemButton.class);
                            startActivity(i13);
                            break;
                     }
                }

            });
          }  
        }
```

Appointment1.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class Appointment1 extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button addApointment;
     String []dateofAppointment;
     String []physicianName;
     Button homepage;
    TableLayout  appointment_table;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.appointment1);
        addApointment=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        homepage=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        System.out.println("in appintment1");
        appointment_table=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.appointment_table);
        AddAppointment obj=new AddAppointment();
        obj.getAppointment();
        dateofAppointment=obj.dateofAppointment;
        physicianName=obj.physicianName;
        fillCountryTable();
        System.out.println("in appintment1 on create");
        addApointment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Appointment1.this,AddAppointment.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        homepage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Appointment1.this,TabBar.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void fillCountryTable() {

        TableRow row;
        TextView t1, t2;
        //Converting to dip unit
        int dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                (float) 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        System.out.println("in appintment1 fill country");
        for (int current = 0; current < dateofAppointment.length; current++) {
            row = new TableRow(this);

            t1 = new TextView(this);
           // t1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
            t2 = new TextView(this);
            //t2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_red));
            t1.setText(physicianName[current]);
            t2.setText(dateofAppointment[current]);


            t1.setTypeface(null, 1);
            t2.setTypeface(null, 1);

            t1.setTextSize(15);
            t2.setTextSize(15);

            t1.setWidth(15 * dip);
            t2.setWidth(15 * dip);
            t1.setPadding(0*dip, 0, 0, 0);
            //t2.setPadding(0*dip, 0, 0, 0);
            row.addView(t1);
            row.addView(t2);

            appointment_table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }
    }
}
```

addappointment.java

```
package com.example.app;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddAppointment extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener,
OnItemSelectedListener  
{

    private Button mSave;
    private Button mDelete;
      String []dateofAppointment=new String[100];
      String []physicianName=new String[100];
    private EditText mPhysicianName;

    // Add Datepicker
    private EditText tvDisplayDate;
    //private DatePicker dpResult;
    private Button btnChangeDate;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    protected static DBHelper1 DB1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_appointment);
        DB1=DBHelper1.getDB();
        // Assignment of UI fields to the variables
                mSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
                mSave.setOnClickListener(this);

                mDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
                mDelete.setOnClickListener(this);


                mPhysicianName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                tvDisplayDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
                setCurrentDateOnView();
                addListenerOnButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        System.out.println("In click ");
        System.out.println("PAtient id " +LoginActivity1.getPatientId());

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.delete:
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Appointment.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // finish();
            break;

        case R.id.save:

            System.out.println("rEGISTER BUTTON CLICK");
            String DateofAppointment = tvDisplayDate.getText().toString();
            String PhysicianName = mPhysicianName.getText().toString();

            boolean invalid = false;

            if (DateofAppointment.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter DateofAppointment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else

            if (PhysicianName.equals("")) {
                invalid = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter PhysicianName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else if (invalid == false) 
        {


            //String DateofAppointment = null;
            addEntry(DateofAppointment, PhysicianName);
            getAppointment();
            Intent i_register = new Intent(AddAppointment.this,
                    Appointment.class);
            startActivity(i_register);
            // finish();
        }

        break;
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //DB1.close();
}

private void addEntry(String DateofAppointment,String PhysicianName) 
{

    SQLiteDatabase db1 = DB1.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put("id", 2);
    values.put("patientid", LoginActivity1.getPatientId());
    values.put("DateofAppointment", DateofAppointment);
    values.put("PhysicianName", PhysicianName);

    try {
        long rowId = db1.insert(DBHelper1.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME10, null, values);
        System.out.println("rowId: "+rowId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "your details submitted Successfully...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getAppointment()
{

    DB1=DBHelper1.getDB();
    String id=String.valueOf(LoginActivity1.getPatientId());
System.out.println("Patient id "+id);
    System.out.println("in getAppointment---1");
  SQLiteDatabase db1 = DB1.getReadableDatabase();
  System.out.println("in getAppointment--3");

    String[] columns = { "DateofAppointment,PhysicianName" };

    String selection = "patientid=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { id };

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {

        cursor = db1.query(DBHelper1.DATABASE_TABLE_NAME10, columns, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

       String dateAppointment=null;
       String physicName=null;
       System.out.println(" Cursor  count "+cursor.getCount());
       for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
       {
           dateAppointment =cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("DateofAppointment")));
           physicName =cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("PhysicianName")));
           dateofAppointment[i]=dateAppointment;
           physicianName[i]=physicName;
           System.out.println("Physicain name "+ physicianName[i]+ " "+i);
          cursor.moveToNext();

       }
       Appointment apt=new Appointment();
       apt.dateofAppointment=dateofAppointment;
       apt.physicianName=physicianName;
       apt.fillCountryTable();
        System.out.println("in getAppointment---4");
        //startManagingCursor(cursor);
    } catch (Exception e)

    {
       System.out.println("Excetion in getAppointment"+e.getMessage());
    }

    int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();
    System.out.println("numberOfRows::"+numberOfRows);

    if (numberOfRows <= 0) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "User Name and Password miss match.Register First.\nPlease Try Again",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }




}


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
{

}



public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/*public static void setDB(DBHelper1 dB2) {
    DB1=dB2;

}*/

//display current date
    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {


        //dpResult =(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, just add 1
            /*.append(year).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
            .append(day).append(" "));*/
        .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));
        // set current date into datepicker
        //dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

        btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
           // set date picker as current date
           return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                      year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
             = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            /*tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year)
               .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(day)
               .append(" "));*/
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                       .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                       .append(" "));
            // set selected date into datepicker also
            //dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

        }

        /*@Override
        public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }*/
    };


}
```

appointment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="This page helps you to take appointments"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="HomePage" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="AddAppointment" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <HorizontalScrollView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffccd0"
    >

    <TextView
            android:text="Appointments"
            android:textColor="#b3000d"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="26dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#ffb0b6"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:typeface="sans"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rl_country_heading"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#555555">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_11"
            android:layout_width="160dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="PhysicianName"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dip">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_12"
            android:layout_width="170dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="DateOfAppointment"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_11">
        </TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_country"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"> -->
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <!-- <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dip"> -->

                <TableLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" android:id="@+id/appointment_table">
                </TableLayout>

            <!-- </LinearLayout> -->
        </ScrollView>
 <!--    </LinearLayout> -->

</LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Logcat

```
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221): Process: com.example.app, PID: 1221
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.Appointment1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at com.example.app.AddAppointment.getAppointment(AddAppointment.java:196)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at com.example.app.Appointment1.onCreate(Appointment1.java:39)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-10 23:58:58.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1221):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You should not instatiate an activity remove this codes
AddAppointment obj=new AddAppointment();
        obj.getAppointment();
        dateofAppointment=obj.dateofAppointment;
        physicianName=obj.physicianName;

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
public class AddAppointment extends ActionBarActivity
```

This

```
 AddAppointment obj=new AddAppointment();
 obj.getAppointment();
```

is the problem. You should not instantiate a Activity class will result in null context.

You should reconsider your design. You can create a non activity class ( a utility class) then create a method there do the work and call that method in Activity class. But you cannot instantiate a Activity class.